# How to call JS functions from Flutter Dart code?

Tags: javascript, flutter-web

I want to be capable of writing a Javascript function that can be called from my `main.dart` file.
When I launch my project I'm faced with this deprecation message:

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
chromewebdata/(index)꞉6904:9:7146
```

These are the modifications I've made to the default project code:

Web/app.js:

```
function alertMessage(text){
    alert(text)
}
```

web/index.html:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

main.dart:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
  void _jsFunction() {
    js.context
        .callMethod('alertMessage', ['Flutter is calling upon Javascript!']);
    var state = js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(js.context['state']);
    print(state['hello']);
  }
```